# Force fake location on device?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to demo my app to my supervisor. At the minute I have set all the testing up so that it works with the highway drive in cali. When I demo it I will be in an office (stationary) so the real location data for the phone wont show the demo results at all.

Is there anyway to make the iphone do the city drive? - When its running natively i.e. not connected to the machine.

Comment: You'll need the coordinates of the drive points, override the CLLocationManager, and start a recurrent timer or gcd source that calls the delegate's didUpdateToLocation: one point at a time. You can get coordinates from http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various `CLLocationManager` simulators on github that you could include in your demo build, such as the `CLLocationManager_simulator` [here](https://github.com/progrmr/CLLocationManager-simulator).

Alternately you can set up your apps to record location data to a file and then create a CLLocationManager simulator that plays back the file.  With that testers can record test drives and then devs can play them back in the office to debug or examine what happened or retest with new builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the Simulator to demo it, there's simulated location available. Look in the Simulator menu under Debug -> Location.

Comment: I wont have access to my mac. I should have posted that in the question